# Which features i can use while testing ubuntu?

Tags: boot

Which features i can use while testing ubuntu (without installing)?I mean am i allowed to install third party softwares while testing it from a livecd or liveusb? Plz answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install packages while testing Ubuntu from livedisk. But before installing any package via `apt-get`, you have to update the repositories  by running `sudo apt-get update` command on terminal.

All installed packages will be lost upon next reboot.

Comment: Nope. You have to run `sudo apt-get update` after any change in repo list.

Comment: @enedil what do you mean by `nope`?

Comment: http://www.internetslang.com/NOPE-meaning-definition.asp @Avinash Raj

Comment: I mean _Why you said nope? What's wrong with my answer?_

Comment: You've said `before installing any package`.

Comment: From a live disk before installing any package, you have run `sudo apt-get update` otherwise it shows the error `Unable to locate package`. Did you try that before?

Comment: I tried and it always worked.

Comment: But it didn't worked for me.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ykhxmocz5vhmmcz/Elementary.png taken from VBox LiveCD